# mongodb high cpu usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed MongoDB 2.4.4 on Amazon EC2 with ubuntu 64 bit OS and 1.6 GB RAM.

On this server, only MongoDB running nothing else.

> But sometime CPU usage reach to 99% and load average: 500.01, 400.73,
>   620.77

I have also installed MMS on server to monitor what's going on server.

Here is MMS detail [image]

> As per MMS details, indexing working perfectly for each queries.
>
> Suspect details as below
>
> 1) HIGH non-mapped virtual memory
>
> 2) HIGH page faults

Can anyone help me to understand what exactly causing high CPU usage ?

**EDIT:**

> After comments of @Dylan Tong, i have reduced active connetions but
>   still there is high non-mapped virtual memory

[image]

Comment: you have a huge number of connections opened. What ops are you performing?

Comment: @DylanTong Generally there are insert,update, read operations. We use MongoDB for reporting database.

Comment: The large number of active connections should explain why you have so much unmapped memory. Also if you have ~13k active connections doing work then I would expect alot of CPU usage. It doesn't sound like your box is very beefy to handle that type of load. Oddly, your opcounters dashboard shows very little ops in the visible timeframe. Is 13k active connections expected? How many clients/threads do you have and what is the configured connection pool size? Are you closing your cursors in your app?

Comment: Also the reason why you have a large number of page faults is because you only have 1.6GB. Unbuntu will probably leave you with at most 1.3G, and your large connection stack is using up a huge chunk. As a result, you'll have a low number of documents in resident memory leading to the page faults.

Comment: @DylanTong Thanks for very useful comments. 13k active connections is not expected at all. Can tell how to find why 13k active connections are there ?

Comment: How do you query MongoDB? Is it through a driver?

Comment: @DylanTong Yes PHP Driver and also Rails MongoDB Driver

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with those drivers, but my suspicion would be that you should be explicitly calling cursor.close() in your code (notice that there is an equivalent # of active cursors as connections), or you have some code that is inadvertently creating some extreme concurrency (async code?).  The latter seems unlikely as you would need alot of clients and threads to pull off 13k. Lastly, upgrading to the latest driver might help. There is a chance that there is a driver issue I'm not aware of.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34742/discussion-between-gbd-and-dylan-tong)

Comment: @DylanTong Cursor connection and DB connection both are different ?

Comment: @DylanTong I have reduced active connections but still there is high non-mapped virtual memory. I have edited my question with latest stat pic.

Comment: 20 active connections on a micro is still very high, and unnecessary if you're only doing ~10 requests per second. Start with one connection and see if there is any need to scale up on more threads. Reporting normally requires low concurrency. Set the connection pool on your driver to something low. Note MongoDB isn't typically CPU bound. IO bound is more common. Share the following info: queries you're running, acpuinfo. and your readahead setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a summary of a few things to look into:

**1. Observed a large number of connections and cursors (13k):**
  - fix: make sure your connection pool is appropriate. For reporting, and your current request rate, you only need a few connections at most. Also, I'm guessing you have a m1small instance, which means you only have 1 core.

**2. Review queries and indexes:**
  - run your queries with explain(), to observe how the queries are executed. The right model normally results in queries only pulling very few documents and utilization of an index.

**3. Memory (compact and readahead setting):**
- make the best use of memory. 1.6GB is low. Check how much free memory you have, and compare it to what is reported as resident. A couple of common causes of low resident memory is due to fragmentation. If there are alot of documents moving, changing size and such, you should run the compact command to defragment your data files. Also, a bad readahead can lead to poor use of memory as well. Check your readahead setting (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man2/readahead.2.html). Try a few values starting with low values (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/). The production notes recommend 32 (for standard 512byte blocks). Sometimes higher values are optimal if your documents are larger. The hope is that resident memory should be close to your available memory and your page faults should start to lower.

If you're using resources to the fullest after this, and you're still capped out on CPU then it means you need to up your resources.

Comment: blockdev --setra <num of blocks> <drive> (http://linux.die.net/man/8/blockdev). I would go through the Production Notes link that I sent you. There are other settings in there that will lower the overhead of your disks and speed up IO.

Comment: I am not much expert in server. Why don't you join us as mongodb server administrator ?

Comment: @GBD Thanks GBD, but I actually work at 10gen (MongoDB Company). I like to help out the MongoDB community in my spare time. Maybe your company can benefit from getting Commercial Support and Consulting from us.

Comment: I am glad that i am getting support from 10gen member. Do you have idea how we can set MongoDB performance benchmark ?

Comment: We're currently working on publishing some performance results, but we have no formal performance benchmarks. Benchmarks rarely reflect actual application performance as they fail to properly simulate specific application workloads. it's particularly difficult to simulate a benchmark for NoSQL properly because of significant design differences; one test can easily favor one system over another. For that reason, engineering hasn't spent time focusing on benchmarking.